# Deleted file not being deleted

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd, windows-7-x64

So I have a file named "Satoshi Urushihara" on my desktop. When I tried to delete it it says:

"This is no longer located in C:\Users\yonechan\Desktop. Verify the items location and try again"

I've tried deleting by clicking it and through CMD. nether seems to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Create a new folder, drag and drop the file into the folder, then delete the folder.

Comment: I get the same error when I try moving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RD/s C:\Users\yonechan\Desktop